# Can I show that a function is not non-negative, if under these conditions?

Tags: systems-of-equations, integral-equations

I was wondering, if it is possible to show, that if I have any function $f$ over $\mathbb{R}$, such that $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x) dx = 1$, $\int_{0}^{\infty} x(f(x)-f(-x)) dx = 0$, and $\int_0^\infty x^2(f(x)+f(-x)) dx = 0$, then f cannot be non-negative.

I tried to write down the conditions on $f$ such that the individual integrals are satisfied, i.e. for the second integral we have either

(I) $f$ is even or

(II) there is some point $x$ such that $f(x)-f(-x)<0$ (and the set of points $x$ for which it holds has positive measure).

And similarly for the last integral, either

(III) $f$ is odd or

(IV) there is some point $x'$ such that $f(x')+f(-x')<0$ (and the set of points $x'$ such that this holds has positive measure).

Based on these conditions, I tried to show that f must be negative at some point in $\mathbb{R}$. And I managed for all cases except (II)+(IV).

For case (II)+(IV) I tried to assume that f was non-negative, but I couldn't reach a contradiction.

I would be very grateful, if anyone could give me a hint as how to prove it.

Comment: @Peter Wouldn't showing it for even functions be either case (I)+(III) or (I)+(IV)? (Because I managed those). 
I don't understand what you mean by "functions satisfying the second condition and not being even, are already pathological). Could you maybe explain that?

Comment: Forget my comment, I must have mixed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very well known non-negative function  satisfying these properties: $f(x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}} e^{-x^{2}/2}$.

The edited question is easy to answer: Suppose $f \geq 0$ a.e. Then the last condition implies that $f(x)+f(-x)=0$ a.e. on $(0,\infty)$ and hence $f=0$ a.e on $\mathbb R$. But then  the first condition does not hold.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the question, the last integral is supposed to be equal to 0, because then it doesn't hold anymore for the function you mention.

Comment: @Ponky The question trivial in that case.